# Access Violation при работе с CSP

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi

Есть библиотека для работы с криптопровайдером на .NET Core. Она работает для VipNet и CryptoPro. Переодически на обращении к статичному типу самой либы вылетает ошибка Access Violation. Происходит раз 30-40 запусков программы, в общем редко но происходит. Не могу понять в чем проблема и как ее решить. Перед всеми обращениями к неуправляемой памяти делаю вывод на консоль поинтеров, но после краша нет в консоли ничего. Весь код рабочий и при остальных запусках все работает как надо. Сама либа подгружается еще на этапе регистрации в IoC судя по Debug логу в вижле. Приложение десктопное. Есть идеи куда воевать?

Answer (score 0):

Threadы есть  ? у меня не давно был похожий случай с либой и за потока при вызове функций либы устоновил `Mutex` (lock/unlock) ошибка пропала

Comment: Потоки есть но не думаю что в этом дело. Запрашивается на отображение информация о сертификатах в одном месте и там падает переодически. А сам класс статический юзается как синглтон так что вероятность того что это многопоточка ничтожна. К библиотеке запросы идут последовательно.  Возможно при инициализации есть какие-то косяки. Проверю отпишу.